Insert x bits at the beginning of binary string
I have a function that inserts x bits with the value 0 at the beginning of a binary string and shifts all existing bits to the right.
This works for all test cases except the last one: 1000 0000 (0x80) becomes 0100 0000 (0x40)
This is correct for the first byte, but by shifting the last bit to the right, a new byte must be created:
0100 0000 0000 0000 (0x40 0x00)
How can I extend my function to this special case and have I overlooked anything else?
Update:
The solution should be to always append a new byte at the end, because with each shift to the right x byte always becomes x + 1 bytes. The mask &0xFF, which previously determined the $shiftedBits, returns 0x00 in the special case, which was not previously taken into account by the if($shiftedBits > 0). So the following should be the solution, right?
if ($shiftedBits >= 0) { /* "if" is not necessary anymore */
   $newBinaryString .= chr($shiftedBits);
}


function insertBitsLeft($binaryString, $numBits) {
    if (!is_numeric($numBits) || $numBits <= 0) {
        return $binaryString;
    }

    // Calculate the number of bytes that can be added at the beginning
    $numBytes = intdiv($numBits, 8);

    // Calculate the remainder (overflow/rest)
    $remainder = $numBits % 8;

    // Add the bytes with a bit value of 0 at the beginning
    $newBinaryString = str_repeat("\x00", $numBytes);

    // Add the overflow/rest by shifting the remaining bits
    if ($remainder > 0 && strlen($binaryString) > 0) {
        $shiftedBits = 0;
        for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($binaryString); $i++) {
            $currentByte = ord($binaryString[$i]);
            $newBinaryString .= chr(($currentByte >> $remainder) | $shiftedBits);
            $shiftedBits = ($currentByte << (8 - $remainder)) & 0xFF;
        }
        if ($shiftedBits > 0) {
            $newBinaryString .= chr($shiftedBits);
        }
    } else {
        if ($numBytes == 0) {
            $newBinaryString = str_repeat("\x00", 1);
        } else if (strlen($newBinaryString) > 0 && $remainder > 0) {
            $newBinaryString .= str_repeat("\x00", 1);
        }

        $newBinaryString .= $binaryString;
    }

    return $newBinaryString;
}

$testCases = [
    // Test Case 1: Normal case, $binaryString is not empty, $numBits = 16
    [
        "input" => ["binaryString" => "\xFF\xFF", "numBits" => 16],
        "expected" => "\x00\x00\xFF\xFF",
        "description" => "Adds 2 zero bytes at the beginning."
    ],
    // Test Case 2: $binaryString is empty, $numBits = 8
    [
        "input" => ["binaryString" => "", "numBits" => 8],
        "expected" => "\x00",
        "description" => "Adds a zero byte when binaryString is empty and numBits = 8."
    ],
    // Test Case 3: $binaryString is empty, $numBits < 8
    [
        "input" => ["binaryString" => "", "numBits" => 5],
        "expected" => "\x00",
        "description" => "Adds a zero byte when binaryString is empty and numBits < 8."
    ],
    // Test Case 4: $binaryString is not empty, $numBits = 7 (remainder)
    [
        "input" => ["binaryString" => "\xFF", "numBits" => 7],
        "expected" => "\x01\xFE",
        "description" => "Adds 7 zero bits and shifts the existing byte by 7 bits."
    ],
    // Test Case 5: $binaryString is empty, $numBits = 0
    [
        "input" => ["binaryString" => "", "numBits" => 0],
        "expected" => "",
        "description" => "Returns an empty string when numBits = 0."
    ],
    // Test Case 6: $binaryString is not empty, $numBits = 0
    [
        "input" => ["binaryString" => "\xAA", "numBits" => 0],
        "expected" => "\xAA",
        "description" => "Returns the original string when numBits = 0."
    ],
    // Test Case 7: $binaryString is not empty, $numBits = 3
    [
        "input" => ["binaryString" => "\xA3", "numBits" => 3],
        "expected" => "\x14\x60",
        "description" => "Adds 3 zero bits and shifts the existing byte by 3 bits."
    ],
    // Test Case 8: $binaryString is not empty, $numBits > length of $binaryString
    [
        "input" => ["binaryString" => "\xAA\xBB", "numBits" => 20],
        "expected" => "\x00\x00\x0A\xAB\xB0",
        "description" => "Adds 20 bits, shifting the last bits of the original string."
    ],
    // Test Case 9: $numBits is negative
    [
        "input" => ["binaryString" => "\xAA", "numBits" => -5],
        "expected" => "\xAA",
        "description" => "Returns the original string when numBits is negative."
    ],
    // Test Case 10: $numBits is not numeric
    [
        "input" => ["binaryString" => "\xAA", "numBits" => "foo"],
        "expected" => "\xAA",
        "description" => "Returns the original string when numBits is not numeric."
    ],
    // Test Case 11: $binaryString is not empty, $numBits = 1
    [
        "input" => ["binaryString" => "\x80", "numBits" => 1],
        "expected" => "\x40\x00",
        "description" => "Shifts the most significant bit of a byte."
    ],
];

foreach ($testCases as $case) {
    $result = insertBitsLeft($case["input"]["binaryString"], $case["input"]["numBits"]);
    if ($result === $case["expected"]) {
        echo "PASS: " . $case["description"] . "\n";
    } else {
        echo "FAIL: " . $case["description"] . "\n";
        echo "Expected: " . bin2hex($case["expected"]) . "\n";
        echo "Got:      " . bin2hex($result) . "\n";
    }
}



Why do you need to do this in the first place?

@Olivier I have data that is updated monthly but does not always change. This saves me space by storing whether the data is still valid in month/bit x. To be able to import historical data, I need to be able to extend an existing checksum string to the left.

Why’s this in the triage queue lol
